# Is accuracy = 1- test error rate

Tags: classification, terminology, accuracy

Apologies if this is a very obvious question, but I have been reading various posts and can't seem to find a good confirmation.  In the case of classification, is a classifier's **accuracy = 1- test error rate**?  I get that accuracy is $\frac{TP+TN}{P+N}$, but my question is how exactly are accuracy and test error rate related.

Answer (score 8):

In principle, *accuracy* is the fraction of properly predicted cases.

This is the same as `1 - the fraction of misclassified cases` or `1 -  the *error* (rate)`.

Both terms may be sometimes used in a more vague way, however, and cover different things like class-balanced error/accuracy or even F-score or AUROC -- it is always best to look for/include a proper clarification in the paper or report.

Also, note that test error rate implies error on a test set, so it is likely 1-test set accuracy, and there may be other accuracies flying around.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the issue I was having is that the terms are used vaguely, and you make a good point that it must be reported in the context of your analysis.  Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 3):

@mbq answered:

> "1-the fraction of misclassified cases, that is *error*(rate)"

However, it seems wrong as misclassification and error are the same thing. See below (from http://www.dataschool.io/simple-guide-to-confusion-matrix-terminology/):

Accuracy: Overall, how often is the classifier correct?
(TP+TN)/total = (100+50)/165 = 0.91

Misclassification Rate: 
Overall, how often is it wrong?
(FP+FN)/total = (10+5)/165 = 0.09
equivalent to 1 minus Accuracy

**also known as "Error Rate"**